# PHP - How to remove/trim HTML from Array?

Tags: php, arrays

Im using get_file_contents to create a Array. Below you can see a `var_dump` of my Array.

How I get this Array?

```
function remap_alternating(array $values) {
    $remapped = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($values) - 1; $i += 2) {
        $remapped[trim($values[$i], ": ")] = trim($values[$i + 1], " ");
    }
    return $remapped;
}

$mapped = remap_alternating($matches[0]);

foreach($mapped as $key => $val) {
}
```

**Result of**: `var_dump($mapped);`

```
array(32) {
  ["<td valign="top" class="maintext"><strong>Age:</strong></td>"]=>
  string(137) "<td class="graytext">21 Years. </td>"

  ["<td valign="top"><strong>Ethnicity:</strong></td>"]=>
  string(122) "<td class="graytext">Black</td>"

  ["<td valign="top" class="maintext"><strong>Location:</strong></td>"]=>
  string(152) "<td class="graytext">Dubai, United Arab Emirates</td>"
```

**My question** is how can I remove HTML code from this Array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is with [strip_tags](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
$clean = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $clean[strip_tags($key)] = strip_tags($val);
}
```

EDIT

In your function, change your line to this

```
$remapped[strip_tags(trim($values[$i], ": "))] = strip_tags(trim($values[$i + 1], " "));
```

You don't even need my snippet then

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please have a look at my code and tell me where to insert your code? Thank you so much.

Comment: Why don't you just add `strip_tags` to your function?

Comment: How to do it? I have tried to insert `strip_tags` almost every where in my codes but all results in ERROR. I have never used it before. Could you please tell me where to insert `strip_tags`?

Comment: You are a HERO!! Thank you so MUCH!! Now I got exactly what I was asking/looking for :D Thanks a million!